# OEM logo doesn't appear on startup

Tags: boot, plymouth, 20.04

Ubuntu 20.04 comes with a new boot screen that is supposed to integrate the logo of the brand of your device. I've seen how this works on other devices, but not my laptop.

I upgraded from 19.10 yesterday, which I installed a few months ago as 16.04 and upgrading to 19.10. I'm not sure my device is Ubuntu-certified. It's a Dell Inspiron R17 N7110.

It's not a must-have feature, but I had my hopes up for a better boot screen (though even without the logo, I think it's a step up)

Comment: The OEM logo only shows when the system is booted in UEFI mode. If you are booted in Legacy BIOS, it does not show, so that's probably why you are not seeing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing this problem too..now fixed it.
I had tried every sort of methods, but didn't work.I did a clean install of Focal Fossa (20.04 LTS) as UEFI, and yay! my Dell OEM logo is showing.
Just install Ubuntu in UEFI mode.

Comment: (Apologies for the late response) My PC doesn't support UEFI, so that's why.

Answer (score 4):

You have to manually enable it.

### In terminal:

1. Install `plymouth-theme-spinner`.

   ```
   sudo apt install plymouth-theme-spinner
   ```

   This is the OEM Boot logo theme
2. Update alternatives for Plymouth

   ```
   sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
   ```

   It'll let you pick a default theme if more than one are installed.
3. Select the `/usr/share/plymouth/themes/bgrt/bgrt.plymouth` theme.
4. Finally run

   ```
   sudo update-initramfs -u
   ```

Then reboot.

Comment: it didnt work HP. i tried the above steps but didnt work. Anything else you have?

Comment: sorry for disturbing but i found out that the logo is not shown in ubuntu installed in legacy boot settings

Comment: I've already got the spinner there, it's the theme that comes with 20.04. (My apologies for the late reply)

Answer (score 0):

For me I had to change

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

in /etc/default/grub

then

```
sudo update-grub
```

Answer (score -2):

I did the same thing through a ansible playbook to also changed the lines inside /etc/default/grub and it works perfectly. When doing the initial install statically assign the IP and once you get the splash screen discussed here just remote in using ssh and make the changed then reboot. The next time the logon screen will appear just fine.

** I have noticed that on different platforms I get different results before the splash screen changes are made.
Dell 7060 give a /dev/SDA clean error.
Dell R640 server gives a black screen with nothing on it.
HP DL20 gives same screen as the Dell 7060 desktop error screen.